# Launch Windows program when external drive connected

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-storage, notifications

In Windows 10, is there any way to launch an existing program (EXE) when a specific USB external disk is connected?

The EXE need not be on the external disk but will need to access files on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mattcollinge.wordpress.com/software/usb-detect-and-launch/

I would try this I have used it before its free for home use and commercial or business use you need a licence.

You can configure what you want to open and for what drive you want the program to open for.

So basically make a Batch file for it to open your program.

@echo off
Cd C:/Test Program
start exampleprogram.exe

save as .bat then use the example configs on the site to get it going.